# An "unofficial" position in a CV

Tags: resume, united-kingdom, employment

I own a small private limited company in the UK.

A person I know (let's call her Alice) has **helped me a bit for free** with a couple of projects of mine (see footnote).

Now, we would like Alice to be able to put this experience in her CV, but we are worried that this could cause problems to either me or to Alice herself.

Problems could be:

- HMRC or anyone else could be suspicious and think I actually paid Alice "off the record"
- maybe it is illegal to have some free help anyway, or it's not illegal but I should have compiled some documentation anyway, I don't know
- maybe a perspective employer of Alice could check some records and notice there's no trace of relationship between her and My Company

So we don't know what to do.

- Can Alice just put that info into her CV without either of us risking anything?
- Or, can I somehow retroactively pay Alice for the work done a few months ago?

**Keep in mind** that *right now* Alice is employed, so that would have to be "paying her for work done a few months ago", I might not be able to pay her now pretending this work has been done now instead of back then.

Also, Alice is not registered as a sole trader or anything like that.

---

**DISCLAIMER**: I will obviously ask **my accountant** before doing anything; you will obviously not be responsible for anything. I'm asking here just to have a provisional opinion.

---

*I have helped Alice for other things, that's beside the point.*

Comment: Care for explaining why the downvote?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a lawyer, and have no experience in the UK.  However, it seems strange to me that there would be anything wrong with a person *volunteering* at your company for reasons of their own.  Common reasons are to get some experience in a new field they wouldn't otherwise be qualified to work at, or don't have a job and want to stay active and current rather than sitting around.

So the answer is to look at this not from the point of view of employment, but rather as a volunteer situation.  That may put it into a different legal perspective.  Surely there are charities in the UK that accept volunteer help, so this must be a well-trodden path.

Answer (score 3):

I also am not a lawyer (but I have some interest in the law).  I do have 35 years experience in the UK workplace.  (I refer to "Alice"‡ rather than "Person A" below, as I find it easier to read)

Don't worry about it.

- It is vanishingly unlikely that HMRC will become aware of the contents of Alice's CV.  Even if they do, they may become suspicious, but a fairly quick review of your books will show that you were not paying her.
- There is no reason not to have free help unless you are in a tightly regulated environment like medicine or banking (and if you were, you would know about it).
- There are no public records which would enable a prospective employer of Alice to find out if she was an employee of yours or not.  I presume if they ask for a reference, you will be happy to provide one.

‡ Yes, I write security software...

Comment: Thank you, I replaced "Person A" instances with "Alice", should be much clearer now.